# How to trim leading zeroes in comma separated values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a table `CUSTOMER (ID,NAME,CORR_ID)`

Sample Data -

```
ID|Name|Corr_ID
1 |John|0239,002319
2 |Mary|000466,00000000054667
```

Here is the output I need to see -

```
ID|Name|Corr_ID
1 |John|239,2319
2 |Mary|466,54667
```

Comment: There are never spaces between the comma and the next numeric value (and they are all numeric values with no other punctuation), right?

Comment: Yes, no spaces after commas... And they are all numeric values. I also want the result set to be ordered by that column.

Comment: Do you really store multiple values using CSV column? If yes, consider normalization and change datatype to INT.

Comment: @lad2025 - No we don't store it that way. It is a column created using LISTAGG. I mentioned it as stored data just for the purpose of asking question.

Comment: If you're building the corr_id via LISTAGG function why not strip off the leading 0' ans it's being built? Build it as:  LISTAGG (LTRIM(column_name,'0'), ',')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
regexp_replace(corr_id, '(,|^)0+', '\1')
```

will strip leading zeros without stripping zeros from 1000 or 2003.

The function looks for EITHER a comma OR the beginning of the string (^) - that is what (,|^) means - and then for one or more consecutive occurrences of the character '0'. It replaces each match with what was in the first pair of parentheses - that is, with the comma or the beginning of the string; it "zaps" all the leading zeros. You need to do it carefully, with the (,|^) - to make sure you don't drop zeros from 1000 or 2003.